# Codeigniter Inserting Multiple Queries to table

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am currently creating an application using codeigniter for an Inventory tracking system.  I've created a way to create/show/update/remove events.  The problem I'm running into is the Inventory Table.  I'm displaying a table with each row a unique product.  I want to be able to update the database inventory tables rows simultaneous. I'm trying something like this in my model:

```
function insert_inventory($data){

    foreach($_POST['product'] as $product){
        $this->db->insert('inventory', $data);
    }
}
```

And this is the Controller:

```
function add_show_inventory() {
    $data['products']=$this->product->get_products();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('skuID', 'skuID', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('brought-in', '"Brought In"', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('finished-with', '"Finished With"', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('deliveries', 'Deliveries');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error-module">', '</div>');

    if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE){
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('menu');
        $this->load->view('inventory/show-add-inventory', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    } else {
        if($_POST){

            //$data['show']=$this->show->get_show();

            $data=array(
                'skuID'=>$_POST['skuID'],
                'product'=>$_POST['product'],
                'deliveries'=>$_POST['deliveries'],
                'brought-in' =>$_POST['brought-in'],
                'finished-with'=>$_POST['finished-with'],
            );

            $this->inventory->insert_inventory($data);
            redirect(base_url().'shows/');
        }
    }
}
```

Any Ideas of how to insert multiple rows at the same time?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your Controller logic is grabbing only one row worth of data.  How would it ever have more than one?  Can you post an example?

Comment: Post an example of what exactly?

Comment: What does the table inventory look like?

Comment: @TommyAdey `skuID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `inv-in` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `inv-out` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `deliveries` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `brought-in` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `add-1` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `add-2` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `total-at-table` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `finished-with` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `sold` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `time-stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `show-date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `showID` varchar(50) NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

Optimize your code for this: [$this->db->insert_batch();](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert)

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: I understand how the insert_batch function should work.  But how can you make it work with a dynamic/unknown amount of products.  I've got an undefined amount of products so I can't hard code each array which is why I was hoping the foreach loop would work.

Comment: Well, you have to work with what you've got in each function call, unless you want to do something like storing the data in a session and then insert a batch once it reaches a certain number of products... but I'd still suggest you go with one product/batch per function call... or optimize the whole app differently.

About your foreach loop - you're not referencing the product variable anywhere... you can use foreach to built the array you'll use for batch insert.

Comment: @TylerCraft it's not about the undefined number of products but the number of defined fields, if you know that a user will enter 5 fields only then that is not a problem, just make a structure similar to the array then use insert_batch

Comment: @tomexsans How can that work if I know the amount of columns for the table... Just not the amount of rows to be inserted...